# Using conditional statement in ipywidgets

Tags: python, conditional-statements, widget

I am still very new to coding and I am playing around with ipywidgets. How do I implement a conditional statement based on the answer of my first widget. For example, if the user selects Yes, it moves on. But if the user selects No, it goes into the second part of the widget.

```
friends = widgets.ToggleButtons(
        options= ["Yes.", "Just me!"])
    
who = widgets.BoundedIntText(
        value=0,
        min=0,
        max=10,
        step=1,
        description='How many?:',
        disabled=False,)
```

I have this, but I have no idea where to start with the conditional statement. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Can you make your question more clear please? Your first widget ('friends') has 2 values ["Yes.", "Just me!"] (there is no No) . From what I understand you want 'Just me!' to do nothing, while 'Yes.' should create the second widget 'who'

Comment: Hi, yes that is exactly what I am trying to go for! I want Yes to go into the next widget who

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for ipywidgets 3.8 or higher. The second widget appears only when the value of the first widget == 'Yes.':

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Output

# create widgets
friends = widgets.ToggleButtons(
        options= ["Just me!", "Yes."])
    
who = widgets.BoundedIntText(
        value=0,
        min=0,
        max=10,
        step=1,
        description='How many?:',
        disabled=False,)

# display the first widget
display(friends) 

# intialize the output - second widget
out = Output() 

def changed(change):
    '''
    Monitor change in the first widget
    '''
    global out
    if friends.value == 'Just me!':  
        out.clear_output() #clear output
        out = Output() # redefine output

    else:
        out.append_display_data(who)
        display(out)
                
# monitor the friends widget for changes
friends.observe(changed, 'value')
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I had a question in regards to using out = Output(), is this just making sure that if I click 'Just me!' nothing else will appear?

Comment: Yes, by including the out.clear_output() , all the created widgets are removed and recreated at will. If you remove that stament, a new 'who' widget will be added to the screen every time you press the 'Yes.' option in the 'friends' button. ==================================================================== If you found my answer useful, please mark it as accepted. To do so, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.